# SharePoint Online 2013 - How to upload a new page layout into master page gallery using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, page-layout

I have created a new custom page layout with custom content type using SharePoint designer 2013 and downloaded a copy of it. Now I have to upload that to another environment using PowerShell.

The written PowerShell script, uploads the the file to master page gallery, but the content type associated with the file is not shown in master page gallery list page. I have to manually edit the properties such as content type and associated content type. Then it will be shown on the list page.
Is there a specific way to upload a page layout into master page gallery?

Could you please help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE Sooraj. Could you edit your post and add the PowerShell Script you're using? This way it would be easier to answer your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can [choose from several sets of APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx) to add/upload publishing page layout. Below is demonstrated how to add/upload publishing page layout via **CSOM** in PowerShell.

**Option 1**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-ClientContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}



Function Deploy-PageLayout([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,[string]$FilePath,[string]$AssociatedContentTypeId)
{
     $pageLayoutContentTypeId = "0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE8110003D357F861E29844953D5CAA1D4D8A3B001EC1BD45392B7A458874C52A24C9F70B"
     $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FilePath)

     $associatedContentType = $Web.AvailableContentTypes.GetById($AssociatedContentTypeId)
     $catalogList = $Web.GetCatalog([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplateType]::MasterPageCatalog)    
     $Web.Context.Load($catalogList.RootFolder)
     $Web.Context.Load($associatedContentType)
     $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()



     $fileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
     $fileInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
     $fileInfo.Content = $fileContent
     $fileInfo.Url = $catalogList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $fileName
     $fileInfo.Overwrite = $true

     $file = $catalogList.RootFolder.Files.Add($fileInfo)
     $Web.Context.Load($file)
     $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()

     $listItem = $file.ListItemAllFields
     #listItem["Title"] = title;
     #listItem["MasterPageDescription"] = description;
     $listItem["ContentTypeId"] = $pageLayoutContentTypeId
     $listItem["PublishingAssociatedContentType"] = [string]::Format(";#{0};#{1};#", $associatedContentType.Name, $associatedContentType.Id.StringValue)
     $listItem["UIVersion"] = [Convert]::ToString(15)
     $listItem.Update()

     $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
}


$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"

$WelcomePageContentTypeId = "0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4"
$WelcomePageFilePath = "C:\Assets\ContosoBlankWebPartPage.aspx"


$context = Get-ClientContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Deploy-PageLayout -Web $context.Web -FilePath $WelcomePageFilePath -AssociatedContentTypeId $WelcomePageContentTypeId
$context.Dispose()
```

**Option 2**

You could utilize [PowerShell cmdlets](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Solutions/PowerShell.Commands) from [PnP project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP), in particular [Add-SPOPublishingPageLayout](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/Solutions/PowerShell.Commands/Documentation/AddSPOPublishingPageLayout.md) command.